# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'access_token' and 'access_token_secret'

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tweepy, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

I am trying to fetch the tweets from Twitter via tweepy API and for that, I have written the following code consisting of sockets for connecting to the pyspark for further analysis of the tweets that are being fetched.
Code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import socket
import json

consumer_key="IvWeydhuRZoHbigNvX9wl8FbX"
consumer_secret="hv9NnWV64f4ECnK3eqJIhwQiu0SoDMtL1b9ImPJJFPwSSKleOg"
access_token="3945967939-cqy1y3J6cPcKi2fohK3qr5QSB2Z3lrOcs863tPI"
access_secret="oJIXDC37NsRU1FNP4jznCyIVwRiBjaHF9L3qsyxybkykS"

class TweetListener(Stream):
    def __init__(self, csocket):
        self.client_socket=csocket
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            msg = json.loads(data)
            print(msg('text').encode('utf-8'))
            self.client_socket.send(msg('text').encode('utf-8'))
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Error %s'%str(e))
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

def send_data(c_socket):
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)
    twtr_stream = Stream(auth, TweetListener(c_socket))
    twtr_stream.filter(track=['ETH'])

s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5000
s.bind((host,port))
print("Active port %s"%str(port))

send_data(c)
```

Error in the ouput:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_22860/3758390964.py in <module>
----> 1 send_data(c)

/tmp/ipykernel_22860/1165989285.py in send_data(c_socket)
      2     auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
      3     auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)
----> 4     twtr_stream = Stream(auth, TweetListener(c_socket))
      5     twtr_stream.filter(track=['ETH'])

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'access_token' and 'access_token_secret'
```

Comment: You should probably pass those arguments to the function like the error message says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks completely contrary to how the `Stream` class is [supposed to be used](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html#using-stream).

The API keys are supposed to be passed as arguments to the `Stream` base class constructor.  There is no need to additionally construct another `Stream` object, or deal with `OAuthHandler` at all.

The quickest way to patch this would be:

```
class TweetListener(Stream):
    def __init__(self, *args, csocket):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.client_socket = csocket
    ...

...

def send_data(c_socket):
    twtr_stream = TweetListener(
        consumer_key, consumer_secret,
        access_token, access_secret,
        csocket=c_socket
    )
    twtr_stream.filter(track=['ETH'])
```

As an aside, I would expect those API keys to be revoked pretty quickly.