# How should I fix " TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'access_token' and 'access_token_secret' "?

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I am working with a Python script which fetches tweets from Twitter via tweepy API.

```
else:
        # create instance of the tweepy tweet stream listener
        tweetlistener = TweetStreamListener()

        # set twitter keys/tokens
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api = API(auth)

        # create instance of the tweepy stream
        stream = Stream(auth, tweetlistener)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "sentiment.py", line 895, in <module>
    stream = Stream(auth, tweetlistener)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'access_token' and 'access_token_secret'
```

The page I have referred:
[TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'access_token' and 'access_token_secret'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581159/typeerror-init-missing-2-required-positional-arguments-access-token-an), It didn't helped much and I am still confused.
What should I do?

**Edit 1:** When I hovered over  `TweetStreamListener()` there is this info:

> (class) TweetStreamListener()

> `__init__( consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, chunk_size=512, daemon=False, max_retries=inf, proxy=None, verify=True )`

So I think, this is where everything is getting messed up.
What do you say about it?

Comment: The Stream constructor takes 4 parameters.  You're only passing two.  Just like the error says.  https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html#using-stream

Comment: As it seems from the linked question, the tweepy API Stream() arguments changed between v3 and v4. Which is causing confusion for a lot of people probably

V3: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.10.0/streaming_how_to.html
V4: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html#using-stream

Comment: @TimRoberts, @klanmiko I got your point, however I think there is something that is breaking at `tweetlistener = TweetStreamListener()`. Please look at post cause I am going to add some details about it.

Comment: I think @klanmiko is correct. Looking at the documentation they linked for tweepy stable you can see `Stream()` does not longer take `Stream(auth, listener)` like you are passing in your code, but `Stream(consumer key, access token)` (and your error message is confirming you should be using this format).

Comment: @Jasper Understood and tried `stream = tweepy.Stream(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)`.Its working now, but I get `[ERROR][tweepy.streaming] Stream encountered HTTP error: 403`. I suspect this is because my App is enabled _Twitter API v2_ and  In documentation it says **StreamingClient allows filtering and sampling of realtime Tweets using Twitter API v2.**